# How to migrate old app to Google Play app signing

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an updated version of an old Xamarin Android app I want to release. I previously set up the signing key which I used to sign the app previously. Apparently, a few months ago I updated to the Google app signing mechanism, but apparently I still need to sign the app myself before uploading. But if I use my old script mechanism, Google tells me "You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate." I can't figure out how to set up the signing with whatever that upload certificate is. Neither the Google nor Xamarin docs are comprehensible to me. I downloaded "upload_cert.der" and "deployment_cert.der" files from Google, but have no idea what to do with them. I tried using Visual Studio to publish, but it says to create Oauth client and enter the client ID and secret, pointing to the Google Play Console, but I can't figure out how to do that. It would be really nice if there were some docs for people in my situation.

Comment: For this problem,  you can go to  google play support for further support.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way I must have regenerated the keystore, which no longer matched the key Google has. I found a backup of the keystore, restored it, and now it works.